# Caught in an endless loop with my C program

Tags: c

In my C program, I have a function (datecheck), to check for valid date entries, but I'm caught in an endless loop. What can I put in there to get out? I've tried return and break commands in "if loops", but they haven't worked. It is using struct datee get_date
and struct datee, and month. Function datecheck is caught in a loop that I can't get out of.

```
int datecheck(void)
{
  struct month months[12] =
  { 31, "Jan", 28, "Feb",
      31, "Mar", 30, "Apr",
      31, "May", 30, "Jun",
      31, "Jul", 31, "Aug",
      30, "Sep", 31, "Oct",
      30, "Nov", 31, "Dec" };

  struct datee today;

  today = get_date();
  printf("\n\nDate is ok.  %s %d, %d\n\n", months[today.month - 1].name, today.day, today.year);
}

struct datee
{
  int month;
  int day;
  int year;
};

struct month
{
  int number_of_days;
  char name[4];  /* must be a 4! */
};


struct datee get_date()
{
  struct month months[12] =
  { 31, "Jan", 28, "Feb",
      31, "Mar", 30, "Apr",
      31, "May", 30, "Jun",
      31, "Jul", 31, "Aug",
      30, "Sep", 31, "Oct",
      30, "Nov", 31, "Dec" };

  int i, notok = 0;
  struct datee today;
  char c;

  // multi trap for a valid date (any error triggers not ok)

  do
  {
      notok = 0;
      printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
      scanf("%d/%d/%d", &today.month, &today.day, &today.year);
      while (c = getchar() != '\n');

      if (today.month < 1 || today.month > 12)
      {
          notok = 1;
          puts("Bad Month");
          continue;
      }//
      if (today.year < 1800 || today.year > 5099)
      {
          notok = 1;
          puts("Bad Year");
          continue;
      }//

      if (today.month == 2 && today.year % 4 == 0 && today.year % 400 != 0)
          months[today.month - 1].number_of_days = 29;

      if (today.day < 1 || today.day > months[today.month - 1].number_of_days)
      {
          notok = 1;
          puts("Bad Day");
          continue;
      }//

  } while (notok == 1);

  return today;

}// end funct
```

Comment: I can't remember, does `continue` in a `do...while` go to the beginning of the loop (skipping the condition) or to the loop condition?

Comment: @TomKarzes That must be the problem then.

Comment: The inner loop, `while (c = getchar() != '\n');` doesn't check for `EOF`, so if it ever gets `EOF` without a newline it will loop forever.  Also, the assignment to `c` is useless, and is assigning the result of the comparison, not the result of `getchar()`.

Comment: @TomKarzes -- "_It goes back to the top of the loop_": `continue` jumps to the [end of the loop body](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.2p2).

Comment: @exnihilo You're right.

Comment: Did you really get this to compile without warnings? Warning means bug, start by clearing those out.

Answer (score -2):

Continue In a loop makes it Skip the satisfied Condition;
Friend I think u are trying For a leap year so first try Block by block code and check with the two while statements and also try using {} for third If condition
also i ain't that good in C++.

Comment: This is a trivial answer. Please try to elaborate your answer in a little bit more sense.